# Angle between siblings in TikZ mindmaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I am not able to set the angle between two siblings in a TikZ mindmap. The code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=orange!40,
    level 1/.append={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}]
\node[root concept]{Root}[counterclockwise from=225]
    child{node {Left node}[counterclockwise from=135]
        child{node {Left1}}
        child{node {Left2}}
        child{node {Left3}}
        child{node {Left4}}
    } $ left
    child{node {Right node}[clockwise from=45]
        child{node {Right1}}
        child{node {Right2}}
        child{node {Right3}}
        child{node {Right4}}
    } %right
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the output is this:

[image: Mindmap]

Neither this instruction:

```
level 1/.append={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
```

nor this one:

```
level 1/.append={sibling angle=90},
```

separate siblings by 90 degrees. Even if I set `sibling angle=180` (or any other value) nothing changes.

What do I do wrong? It should be something very simple, but I cannot see it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.append style` instead of `.append` in your level styleset:

```
...
level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45}]
...
```

This leads to following image:
[image: rendered image]

Comment: Thanks - it was easy but my eye is not yet trained on TikZ...